# How could I get Xuggler jars for Windows XP?

Tags: java, video, mpeg, xuggler

I could not find the jar file for Xuggler. How can I get them?

Answer (score 2):

See [Downloading & Installing](http://www.xuggle.com/downloads). It describes how to get dependencies using Maven or Ivy. But you can also download these [directly](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/), the link is mentioned under `Using Xuggler WITHOUT Apache Maven or Apache Ivy` section. There is also a table below that section, which can help you pick the files you need for your particular architecture.

Comment: the `xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar` is all that is needed??? I am a beginner and downloaded it from the direct download link. I **do not** do Maven or Ivy